# asp.net MVC 3 RegisterArea with multiple optional id's not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, optional-parameters, areas, maproute

I am trying to capture multiple optional parameters in an ASP.NET web application.  When I define the `MapRoute` in `RegisterArea()`, it is breaking the `Html.ActionLink()` methods.

The following code works:

```
    Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext)
        context.MapRoute( _
            "Register_default", _
            "Register/{controller}/{action}/{id1}", _
            New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id1 = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
    End Sub
```

but when I modify the URL to include multiple optional parameters (below), it is causing all of my `Html.ActionLink()` methods to create anchor tags with empty hrefs.  Can someone tell me what is causing this to happen?

```
    Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext)
        context.MapRoute( _
            "Register_default", _
            "Register/{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}", _
            New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id1 = UrlParameter.Optional, .id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, .id3 = UrlParameter.Optional, .id4 = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in MVC3/System.Web.Routing:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't have a route that has several optional parameters, only the last parameter can be optional precisely because of the problem you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  However, if that is the case, wouldn't it choke on url's with missing id's?  From my example above,

myurl.com/Register/Signup/WhyRegister
myurl.com/Register/Signup/WhyRegister/5/
myurl.com/Register/Signup/WhyRegister/5/25
myurl.com/Register/Signup/WhyRegister/5/25/125
myurl.com/Register/Signup/WhyRegister/5/25/625

all are correctly passing id's to the controller action and

myurl.com/Register/Signup/WhyRegister/5/25/625/3125 

will give a 404

Comment: edit: the last 2 urls in the last comment should read ...5/25/125/625 and ...5/25/125/625/3125